# Haskell redefine words function with recursion

Tags: function, haskell, recursion

I need to redefine the words function with recursion. I have 2 helper function but I can't really manage to put together the final function. Any ideas?

```
takeWord :: String -> String
takeWord  ""      = ""
takeWord (' ':xs) = ""
takeWord (x  :xs) = x : takeWord xs

dropWord :: String -> String
dropWord  ""      = ""
dropWord (' ':xs) =  ' ' : xs
dropWord (x  :xs) =  dropWord xs

words' :: String -> [String]
words' "" = []
words' (' ':xs) = takeWord xs : words' xs
words' (x:xs) =  takeWord (x:xs) : words' (dropWord xs)
```

The result for this input `"   Correct   answer   is   this"` should be `["Correct","answer","is","this"]`. Now I'm getting this output: `["","","Correct","Correct","","","answer","answer","","","is","is","","","this","this"]`

Comment: (1) You need to drop a word from the tail every time you take a word. (2) when you take a word, you need to check if it's empty.

Comment: When you try, what goes wrong for you? Include your attempted code above.

Comment: @Michael Litchard it’s there the words’ function is it which should do the work. takeWord is taking the first word of a string dropWord is dropping the first word of a string and words’ should make a list of words from a string with the help of the previous two function.

Comment: Doh! I see it now.

Comment: `words' (' ':xs) = takeWord xs : words' xs` looks like it is duplicating words, since `xs` is used twice. Are you sure you don't need to recurse as `words' (dropWords xs)` or something similar?

Comment: @chi Now it looks like this: ```words' (' ':xs) = takeWord xs : words' (dropWord xs)``` and the output is : ```["","","Correct","","","answer","","","is","","","this"]``` so the problem is it's only dropping one ```' '``` instead of three which i have in the input

Comment: Maybe I'd try instead `words' (' ':xs) = words' xs` to skip the leading spaces and see what happens.

Comment: @Skyline If you have a result such as `["","","Correct","","","answer","","","is","","","this"]`, you could just try to pass it to `filter (not . null)` . Not massively elegant, but it would work.

Comment: @chi Thank you now it's working!

Comment: @Skyline  Great ! BTW it is perfectly acceptable for you to answer your own question. But you are not supposed to (self)accept your own answer before waiting for a couple of days.

Comment: @jpmarinier Why can't I mark the answers useful or accept them as an answer? I could do that earlier at an other question

Comment: @Skyline I am a bit confused - there are no answers at all, only comments here, so you cannot accept a non-existent answer. You can just upvote the comments by clicking on their upward-pointing triangle.

Comment: @jpmarinier Yes, but can't see the triangles at the comments.

Comment: @Skyline  No idea why. On my screen, the triangle appears in grey at the left of the comment, above the little flag. Note that the flag is only to be clicked when you want to mark the comment as abusive. One of your own comments has been upvoted twice, including by me. So I see a "2" digit just left of its triangle. And the triangle is now orange instead of grey.

Answer (score 0):

Got the working solution from @chi

"Maybe I'd try instead words' (' ':xs) = words' xs to skip the leading spaces and see what happens."